# How can retrieve cell address that match criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, cells

In column A are various products (A2:A100), in column B are different numbers (B2:B100).

In cell G2 is criteria from column A.

With the formula `{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$100=G2;$B$2:$B$100))}`, I can find the highest value for a specific product in a sales list with multiple products.

Or I can use the sumproduct formula `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$100=G2)*($B$2:$B$100)))`.

But how can I find the cell address for the highest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ugly solution. Just `MATCH` the result of the formula you have in the same conditional array you passed to the `MAX` function. Then pass the resulting index number to the `ADDRESS` function.

```
=ADDRESS(1+MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$100=$G$2,$B$2:$B$100)),IF($A$2:$A$100=$G$2,$B$2:$B$100),0),2)
```

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There's probably a better way to go about this, but this was my first thought.

Comment: Excellent. There is not a ugly solution if it works.

Comment: +1! I agree. This is not ugly; it’s what Excel forces you to do. I was working on something similar, but yours is more elegant and you got it in faster. A couple of notes: (1) If this formula goes into cell `H2`, and there are other product names in `G3`, `G4`, …, then your references to `$G$2` should be changed to `$G2` or just `G2`. (2) To increase portability/flexibility, you might replace the `1` with `ROW($A$2)-1` (e.g., in case there’s another batch of data in rows 102-200).